# Can ansible define the value of an expression as a variable?

Tags: ansible

i have a playbook like this below.

```
   - name: ensure crm service is exist
     shell: crm resource status {{item.service}}
     register: is_service_exist
     with_items: "{{crm_services}}"
     run_once: true
     delegate_to: "{{controller_master}}"
     when: crm_services is defined
     ignore_errors: True

   - name: msg
     vars:
       service_is_exist: var[{{is_service_exist.results[0].stderr.find('not found')}}==-1]
     debug: msg={{service_is_exist}}]

   - name: stop crm service
     shell: crm resource stop {{item.service}}
     with_items: "{{crm_services}}"
     run_once: true
     delegate_to: "{{controller_master}}"
     when: crm_services is defined and is_service_exist.results[0].stderr.find('not found')==-1

   - name: uninstall current rpm packages
     shell: rpm -e --nodeps {{item.package}}
     with_items: "{{packages}}"
     ignore_errors: True
```

I want to know whether the crm_service is exist, if crm_service is exist,stop the service and uninstall current rpm packages.
I think `is_service_exist.results[0].stderr.find('not found')==-1` is not easy to read, so i want to set the expression as a variable, can ansible do it?

i have tried `var[{{is_service_exist.results[0].stderr.find('not found')}}==-1]` , but the output is like this "msg": "var[-1==-1]"

So, can ansible define the value of an expression as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I typically use a [`set_fact`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/set_fact_module.html) after each `register` to get rid of the junk data.

```
- name: ensure crm service is exist
  shell: crm resource status {{item.service}}
  register: is_service_exist
  with_items: "{{crm_services}}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{controller_master}}"
  when: crm_services is defined
  ignore_errors: True

- set_fact:
    is_service_exists: "{{is_service_exist.results[0].stderr.find('not found') == -1}}"

- name: stop crm service
  shell: crm resource stop {{item.service}}
  with_items: "{{crm_services}}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{controller_master}}"
  when: crm_services is defined and is_service_exist
```